# Python iloc loop is taking too much time to execute. Technical analysis calculation

Tags: python, pandas, performance, iteration, technical-indicator

I developed a code to analyze a large set of stock prices. Basically it uses two technical indicators (MACD and EMA) and creates a Technical analysis flag.

The code is working, which is great but it is taking too much time to execute, most likely because of the iterations using iloc. Do you have some suggestions to improve speed? I provide an example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(low=2, high=5.5, size=(10000,)), columns=['Close'])
close = df['Close'].astype(float)

def MACD(first,second,signal):
    df['EMA'+str(first)] = close.ewm(span=first).mean()
    df['EMA'+str(second)] = close.ewm(span=second).mean()
    df['MACD']=df['EMA'+str(first)]-df['EMA'+str(second)]
    df['signal']=df.MACD.ewm(span=signal).mean()
    df['MACD_ind'] = 0
    
    for i in range (second+signal, len(df)):
        if df.MACD.iloc[i]>df.signal.iloc[i] and df.MACD.iloc[i-1]<df.signal.iloc[i-1]:
            df.loc[i,'MACD_ind']=1
        if df.MACD.iloc[i]<df.signal.iloc[i] and df.MACD.iloc[i-1]>df.signal.iloc[i-1]:
            df.loc[i,'MACD_ind']=-1
                
def EMA(first,second):
    df['EMA'+str(first)] = close.rolling(window=first).mean()
    df['EMA'+str(second)] = close.rolling(window=second).mean()
    df['EMAdif'] = df['EMA'+str(first)]-df['EMA'+str(second)]
    df['EMA_ind'] = 0
    for i in range (second, len(df)):
        if df.EMAdif.iloc[i]>0 and df.EMAdif.iloc[i-1]<0:
            df.loc[i,'EMA_ind']=1
        if df.EMAdif.iloc[i]<0 and df.EMAdif.iloc[i-1]>0:
            df.loc[i,'EMA_ind']=-1


split_time = time.time()
TA_ind=list()

MACD(12, 26, 9)
TA_ind.append('MACD_ind')
print("MACD--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - split_time))
split_time = time.time()    
        
EMA(20,50)
TA_ind.append('EMA_ind')
print("EMA--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - split_time))
split_time = time.time()
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this dataframe function called shift that helped me out quite a bit.

```
def MACD(first,second,signal):
    df['EMA'+str(first)] = close.ewm(span=first).mean()
    df['EMA'+str(second)] = close.ewm(span=second).mean()
    df['MACD']=df['EMA'+str(first)]-df['EMA'+str(second)]
    df['signal']=df.MACD.ewm(span=signal).mean()
    df['dif']=df['MACD']-df['signal']
    df['dif_shift']=df.dif.shift(1)
    df['MACD_ind'] = 0
    df['MACD_ind']=np.where((df['dif']>0) & (df['dif_shift']<0),1,df['MACD_ind'])
    df['MACD_ind']=np.where((df['dif']<0) & (df['dif_shift']>0),-1,df['MACD_ind'])
                
def EMA(first,second):
    df['EMA'+str(first)] = close.rolling(window=first).mean()
    df['EMA'+str(second)] = close.rolling(window=second).mean()
    df['EMAdif'] = df['EMA'+str(first)]-df['EMA'+str(second)]
    df['EMAdif_shift'] = df.EMAdif.shift(1)
    df['EMA_ind'] = 0
    df['EMA_ind']=np.where((df['EMAdif']>0) & (df['EMAdif_shift']<0),1,df['EMA_ind'])
    df['EMA_ind']=np.where((df['EMAdif']<0) & (df['EMAdif_shift']>0),-1,df['EMA_ind'])
```

Answer (score -1):

Loop through dictionaries is much faster than loop through `DataFrame`. So you can convert your `DataFrame` to dictionary. But you can't use pandas built in functions like `MACD` or `ewm`. So you should write this functions by yourself. Then as a result you have much faster program. As a example, I do this with your dataframe. First i loop through `DataFrame` itself and then i convert it to dictionary and loop through it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(low=2, high=5.5, size=(10000,2)), columns=['Close', 'Open'])
st = time.time()
for i in range(len(df)):
    a = df.iloc[i]['Close'] - df.iloc[i]['Open']
print(time.time() - st)
```

Execution time for this one was `2.005403757095337`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(low=2, high=5.5, size=(10000,2)), columns=['Close', 'Open'])
df_dict = df.to_dict()
st = time.time()
for i in range(len(df)):
    a = df_dict['Close'][i] - df_dict['Open'][i]
print(time.time() - st)
```

But execution time for this one was `0.0029413700103759766`. It means second method is approximately a thousand time faster!

Comment: Hi Mohammed, I cannot use your example with the functions I have created (MACD, EMA).

Do you know why that is? And if you have a way of making it work?

Comment: Hi! What was the problem?

Comment: The MACD_ind and EMA_IND are all zeros went they are transformed from dict to df

Comment: Maybe it is because some issue in MACD or ema functions.

Comment: This is a bad solution, because even if it's faster than an iloc loop, it's still slower than not looping at all! The fastest way to subtract two aligned series is to do `df['Close'] - df['Open']`, and let numpy vectorize the calculation.

Comment: In the question, some code applied on data. It is not as simple as an subtraction between two columns. I write a subtraction as an example to make comparison between execution times.